# Javscript App is running on local Host but when it is deployed it not running properly

Tags: javascript, html, weather

i have made a weather app using accuweather api ,which is working fine on the local host but when it is deployed it does not perform its functions

[this is the error which am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjN3I.png)

Comment: Does your site use `SSL` ? (https protocol)

Comment: Where is the site deployed ? the Api it is using should be http and your site should be https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [this blog post](https://blog.mozilla.org/tanvi/2013/04/10/mixed-content-blocking-enabled-in-firefox-23/) about mixed content:

> **What is Mixed Content?**
> When a user visits a page served over HTTP,
> their connection is open for eavesdropping and man-in-the-middle
> (MITM) attacks. When a user visits a page served over HTTPS, their
> connection with the web server is authenticated and encrypted with SSL
> and hence safeguarded from eavesdroppers and MITM attacks.
>
> However, if an HTTPS page includes HTTP content, the HTTP portion can
> be read or modified by attackers, even though the main page is served
> over HTTPS. When an HTTPS page has HTTP content, we call that content
> “mixed”. The webpage that the user is visiting is only partially
> encrypted, since some of the content is retrieved unencrypted over
> HTTP. The Mixed Content Blocker blocks certain HTTP requests on HTTPS
> pages.

As I can see in your screenshot, the API is integrated over HTTP. You probably use HTTPS on your production server.